# create spinner options from json data / array

Tags: java, android, json, spinner

**1. My question: How do I take my JSON data and parse it into an array that I can use in my spinner.**

Below is my json data:

```
[["Mike Test 1"],["Mike Test 2"],["hello world"],["TEST MIKE 4"],["TEST MIKE 6"],["aliens,crazy stuff"],["Alien"],["american flags,flags"]]
```

My script calls a function that gets the data. I know that is working because I have toasted the return value. It should then loop through and assign the values to a new array that is used in the spinner.

Below is my java:

```
  Spinner areaspinner;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    JSONArray jsonArray;

    try {
    //SETTINGS AND METHOD THAT GETS THE DATA
        String spinnerContentType = "styles";
        String spinnerURL = "getStyles.php";
        String spinner_data =  DataCall.getJSON(spinnerURL,spinnerContentType); 

     //NEW JSONArray OBJECT
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(spinner_data);

        final String[] array_spinner = new String[jsonArray.length()]; 

        int show_total = jsonArray.length();
        //CHECK HOW MANY ITEMS ARE RETURNED
        Toast.makeText(flash_tattoo.this, show_total + "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            //LOOP AND ASSIGN TO ARRAY
            String styleValue = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0).getString(i); 
            array_spinner[i] = styleValue;

        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,array_spinner);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        areaspinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    }catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is my spinner layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/text1" 
  style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle" 
  android:singleLine="true" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
  android:textColor="#e70909"
/>
```

Comment: Do you see the options when replacing adapter.setDropDown.. with this in your code, adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Comment: Are you getting the data of Json in array_spinner.

Comment: @rochdev Changing the setdropdownviewresource did not help. Thanks though.

Comment: I see the word "areaspinner" only once in your code.  Is that the correct name?  Where are you instantiating that?

Comment: @Thunder Rabbit I added the areaspinner at the top of the code.

Comment: @Thunder Rabbit your feedback '"areaspinner" only once in your code. Is that the correct name? Where are you instantiating that?' actually helped me fix my issues. Thanks and +1

Comment: @Denoteone, i am trying to populate the spinner with the json values, can you please send me your code to this mail.. srikanth.gnani@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like `areaspinner` is `null`.

To add a spinner you have something like this in your main.xml.

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/mySpinnerText" />
```

Then in `onCreate()`

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);       
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Your post and one of the comments help me figure out what the issue was. I was creating my spinner but I was not adding the spinner to a view since it was in my layout it was still coming up and that is what confused me. Thanks and +1